# Is there any way to define more than 1 SOQL quires in a batchable class start method

Tags: apex, batch, schedulebatch

I have run into a case where i have to do same operation via batch over records in same object. But i cannot construct a query which can retrieve all of those records. Is there is way to achieve it with a single batchable class or i would have to create multiple classes.

Best Regards
Shanker Paudel

Comment: Store those record id in a instance variable(Use stateful), then in Finish call again.

Comment: Hi, please add some more details to your question as it is unclear why you cannot construct a query in this context. You say it is for the same type of object. In which case, why can't you have different "parts" of the WHERE clause looking for specific sub-sets of the instances?

Comment: As a literal answer to your titular question: no, not when returning SOQL via a query locator. BUT you can select objects based on multiple clauses in a WHERE. E.g. "SELECT Id FROM Xyz__c WHERE (A__c = '123' AND B__c = 'xyz') OR (A__c = '987' AND B__c = 'abc')"

Comment: @PhilW thanks for your feedback. Queries are complicated and there are 13-14 quires. We have inherited this codebase. were not looking to change anything however i got this OR idea moment ago and was discussing with my colleague. This will workout. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A batch's start method can only return a single SOQL query when using query locators.

However, if you are wanting to query the same object type but with multiple different WHERE selection clauses, and you then want to just apply the same logic to them, this is a simple matter of appropriately parenthesizing and combining the clauses into a single WHERE. For example, if your first query is looking for instances matching:

```
A__c = '123' AND B__c = 'xyz'
```

while your second query is looking for instance matching:

```
A__c = '987' AND (B__c = 'abc' OR C__c = 999)
```

then you can construct your query as:

```
SELECT Id, ... FROM MyObject__c WHERE
    (A__c = '123' AND B__c = 'xyz') OR
    (A__c = '987' AND (B__c = 'abc' OR C__c = 999))
```